# SQL database get all dates between two dates in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a possible way to get all the dates between a given range then align/bind it with the data in the database?

I am currently working on a DTR System wherein the Employee's time-in/out in a day is gathered. I want to print all the dates in between the range and insert the time punched and if no punch was done during the day, an ABSENT note will appear.

Example:

```
Date from: 1/1/2018
Date to: 15/1/2018

Output:
Date     | Time in AM |  Time out AM |
1/1/2018 | 8:00 am    |  12:00 am    |
2/1/2018 | 7:50 am    |  12:10 am    |
3/1/2018 | ABSENT     |  ABSENT      |
. . . and so on . . .
```

Thanks in advance

This is the stored procedure

**UPDATE：**

This is the **schema** 
[image: schema],

this is the **output**

[image: output]

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

The code I did for the AM Time-in/out was this

```
    DECLARE @AM DATETIME,@AM_MID DATETIME,@AM_OUT DATETIME,@ABSENT NVARCHAR, @Four INt, @IN_AM DATETIME, @OUT_AM DATETIME; 
SET @AM = '12:01:00 AM';
SET @AM_MID = '10:00:00 AM';
SET @AM_OUT = '12:59:59 PM';
SET @IN_AM = '8:00:00 AM';
SET @ABSENT = 'ABSENT';
SET @Four = 4;

Select usrinfo.Name as [Fullname], FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy') as [Date],

CASE
WHEN max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1' and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_MID and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end)  IS NULL
THEN '--'
ELSE
 max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1' and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_MID and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end)
END
as [AM Time-in],

CASE
WHEN min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) IS NULL
THEN '--'
ELSE
min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end)
END
as [AM Time-out]



from NGAC_AUTHLOG as auth INNER JOIN
     NGAC_USERINFO as usrinfo ON usrinfo.ID = auth.UserID INNER JOIN
     NGAC_GROUP as grop ON grop.ID = usrinfo.GroupID 

where auth.AuthResult ='0' AND usrinfo.GroupID != '1' 

group by FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),usrinfo.Name,  usrinfo.ID, usrinfo.Description, grop.Description
order by FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy') ASC;
```

The code works that I get the **TransactionTime** of the Employee then it will be classified whether it is an **IN** or an **OUT** based on its **FunctionKey**. Once classified, the code will identify the time-in/out in line with the date. The problem I was facing was that I wanted to show the rest of the dates in a given range then classify whether it has data or none, if none then the output to **Time-in/out** will be **Absent** instead of a **--**

I am sorry if I am giving you some trouble Sirs. I am kinda new to this kind of things.

Again thanks for the help sirs.

Comment: Could your give us table schema and mock data?
Example  just your expectation result. We can not answer you with out table schema and mock data ..

Comment: Sometimes (often) it can be easier to do it in an application layer than to bend SQL.

Comment: @daniel.shih I have updated my post. I have my tables there and the output I am receiving. The output was based on a stored procedure I have created.

Comment: @daniel.shih i also have created a function for returning a list of dates and when I try to combine it with my stored procedure, this error shows 'Subquery returned more than 1 value.'

Comment: What's the field represents `Time-in` on your table?
Could you get us some mock data from your table? thanks.

Comment: @daniel.shih I have included the code I did, as well as the activity how the Time-in/out was retrieved. Sori sir for the trouble. Im kinda new to this kind of things

Comment: Use a left join with a pre-populated calendar table. If you don't have a calendar table, you can use a recursive cte instead.